# How to refering a static variable in a class static member?

Tags: c++

I'm tring to encapsulate a C module into C++ classes.

In the C implementation there is a function returing a pointer to a static const

```
const BIGNUM *BN_value_one(void)
{
    static const BN_ULONG data_one = 1L;
    static const BIGNUM const_one =
        { (BN_ULONG *)&data_one, 1, 1, 0, BN_FLG_STATIC_DATA };

    return (&const_one);
}
```

I'm tring to make it a static method in a class with a destructor doing some releasing actions

```
class BigNumber
{

    struct deleter
    {
        void operator() (BIGNUM *it)
        {
            BN_free(it); // The freeing operation provided by origin C library
        }
    };


    using BN_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, deleter>;

    /* The OpenSSL BIGNUM pointer */
    BN_ptr bn;

public:
    BigNumber() : bn(BN_new(), ::BN_free) {}
    BigNumber(BigNumber &&other) : bn(std::move(other.bn)) {}
    BigNumber(const BigNumber &other) : bn(BN_new(), ::BN_free)
    {
        ::BN_copy(bn.get(), other.bn.get());
    }
    BigNumber(BIGNUM *src) : bn(src, ::BN_free) {}

    static const BigNumber one()
    {
        static const BigNumber o(const_cast<BIGNUM *>(::BN_value_one()));
        return o;
    }
}
```

Since the `one()` method returning a `unique_ptr` to a static variable in `BN_value_one`, it will occurs a segmentation fault when destructing the returned value.

Is there any way the avoid such destruction, or any better encapsulation?

Comment: just don't use a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Presumably, you want to wrap up the magic `one()` value in a `BN_ptr` so you have a consistent interface? Well, you're either going to have to create a new `one` value every time the function is invoked, or you're going to have to use a different wrapper class. Is it essential you use `unique_ptr` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using the openssl library you don't have to use `BN_free()` because your code never allocated a `BIGNUM` with `BN_new()`. For more explanation see this [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bn_free).

So you don't need the `unique_ptr` nor the deleter.

**Edit #1:**

I see that your class can also hold allocated `BIGNUM` values. So there are two possibilities to distinguish between allocated and not allocated `BIGNUM` values.

1. Your BigNumber class could provide two different constructors. You can save the state of allocation in a flag and check it in the deleting routine of the `unique_ptr`.
2. You could use polymorphism to provide two different classes that inherits from one interface class. The one class implements a deleter that does nothing and the other one implements one that actually call `BN_free()`.

**Edit #2:**

Now your code is more complete. You could write an addional constructor that takes a pointer to a const `BIGNUM` that uses an own dummy free function. You have to avoid the `const_cast` if you use this constructor.

```
BigNumber(const BIGNUM *src) : bn(src, ::BN_dummy_free) {}
```

The dummy free should look like this:

```
void BN_dummy_free(BIGNUM *a) {}
```

That should work with your code and will not end in a segmentation fault. So you could take allocated and non allocated BIGNUMs.

Also you should take care at your copy constructor, because it will always use `BN_free()`. You should copy the used deleter function, which could may be the `BN_dummy_free()` function.

Comment: The class do hold the allocated value in most cases... I've edited for that :)

Comment: Thanks for making things clearer. I edited my answer and hope that this will help you.